# Why UIButton.layer.maskedCorners accept assign an explicit array and not an array variable?

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift why this does work?

```
let button = UIButton()
button.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
```

And this does not?

```
let corners : [CACornerMask] = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
let button = UIButton()
button.layer.maskedCorners = corners
```

I.E. explicit assigning an array to `maskedCorners` is fine but assign an array variable is not.

The error is:

> cannot assign value of type '[CACornerMask]' to type 'CACornerMask'
>   button.layer.maskedCorners = corners

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `corners` constant is the wrong type. `[CACornerMask]` makes it an array of `CACornerMask`. You want it to be type `CACornerMask`. That's declared as type NS_OPTIONS, which gets mapped to a Swift option set. (`OptionSet`)

The code `[.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]` looks like array syntax, but it's not. It's semantic sugar that lets you specify different bit masks into a C flags variable (which is what a Swift option set maps to.)

To quote Apple's docs: “Swift also imports C enumerations marked with the NS_OPTIONS macro as a Swift option set”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 4 beta).” iBooks.

Comment: Nice! Got it, but then another question, this `[.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]` is not an array of `CACornerMask` and should be declared as so? I ask because if I do this `let a : String = ["a", "b"]` the code doesn't compile.

Comment: Saw your edit, this really got me confused as I mentioned in my last comment about the `String` array case.

Comment: Go read the section on option sets in the Apple iBook "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C." It explains the topic much better than I could.

Comment: There's also a long section on [**OptionSet**](https://swiftdoc.org/v4.2/protocol/optionset/) (link) at swiftdoc.org.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
let corners : CACornerMask = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
let button = UIButton()
button.layer.maskedCorners = corners
```

You are assigning the wrong type to the required type

Answer (score 1):

Well, I made a solution to this problem.

Create an extension of UIView

```
extension UIView{
    
    enum RoundCornersAt{
        case topRight
        case topLeft
        case bottomRight
        case bottomLeft
    }
    
        //multiple corners using CACornerMask
    func roundCorners(corners:[RoundCornersAt], radius: CGFloat) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [
            corners.contains(.topRight) ? .layerMaxXMinYCorner:.init(),
            corners.contains(.topLeft) ? .layerMinXMinYCorner:.init(),
            corners.contains(.bottomRight) ? .layerMaxXMaxYCorner:.init(),
            corners.contains(.bottomLeft) ? .layerMinXMaxYCorner:.init(),
        ]
    }
    
}
```

Now you can use it.

```
 let corners:[UIView.RoundCornersAt] = [.topLeft,.bottomRight]
 button.roundCorners(corners: corners, radius: 20)
```